# A batch to insert 41000 task records

Tags: apex, batch

I want to insert task records around 41k. I used below batch class. This seems running but I can't find any records creating.

```java
public class BatchInsert implements Database.Batchable<Task> {
    Task[] records;
    public BatchInsert(Task[] taskSO) {
        records = taskSO;
    }
    public task[] start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        system.debug('Start batch');
        return records;
    }
    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, Task[] scope) {
        system.debug('execute batch');
        Database.insert(scope, false);
    }
    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        system.debug('finish batch');
    }
}
```

I'm calling this batch using below

```
List<Task> tList = new List<Task>();
for(integer i = 0; i < 41000; i++){
    task t = new task();
    t.subject = 'call';
    t.whoId = '*here some lead Id*';
    tList.add(t);
}

Database.executeBatch(new BatchInsert(tList));
```

can anyone please correct my code here

Comment: Any errors in the logs?

Comment: Is your batch class an actual class, or is your batch class part of your anonymous apex? Does this class compile (I think it should be `implements Database.Batchable<SObject>`?
What does your debug log show?

Comment: `Database.insert(scope, false);` ignores all DML errors. For example, you might have a custom validation rule or trigger that's blocking the creation of the records. You'll need to check your logs to figure out what's going on.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcfox and Derek F for responding my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I got the issue. For some testing I wanted thousands of records in my dev org. So I chose batch insert. When I try to insert single record it throws storage limit exceeded exception. So this could be the reason why the records were not inserted.

Answer (score 1):

As you have already figured out the answer and some suggestions in comments, on a separate note to better handle bulk insertion here is what I think.

From what I have experienced, passing a large number from records in constructor fails with an exception of `Batchable instance is too big`. Because of large data flowing into constructor.

What you can do is.

Create `IntegerIterator` class.

```
public class IntegerIterator implements Iterable<Integer>, Iterator<Integer> {
    Integer counter;

    public IntegerIterator(Integer counter) {
        this.counter = counter;
    }

    public Boolean hasNext() {
        return counter > 0;
    }

    public Integer next() {
        return counter--;
    }

    public Iterator<Integer> iterator() {
        return this;
    }
}
```

And then use this in your batch.

```
global class BigObjectInsertHelper implements Database.Batchable<Integer> {

    global Iterable<Integer> start(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        return new IntegerIterator(100000);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext param1, List<Integer> param2) {
        for (Integer i = 0; i < param2.size(); i++) {
            System.debug(param2.get(i));
        }
    }

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext param1) {
        System.debug('Finished');
    }
}
```

You can add your task creation logic under execute which will receive `param2` size of always 200.

And technically this can support upto `50 million` loops. Which will practically be impossible, but there is no hard limit on `Iterable`